# Hold list of currently active SoundEffectInstances

Tags: c#, audio, monogame

I'm currently trying to make a SoundManager class for my game. It's supposed to hold a list of all currently playing SoundEffectInstances, so I can loop this list to pause (and resume) all Sounds, for example when the game is paused.

My Play function is pretty straight forward:

```
    public static void PlaySound(string name)
    {
        sTestSoundInstance = sTestSound.CreateInstance();
        sAllSounds.Add(sTestSoundInstance);
        sTestSoundInstance.Play();
    }
```

However, I can't wrap my head around how I can check if a sound has finished playing, and when I can remove it from sAllSounds. Please consider there will be different Sounds of different leghts. Any thought on this is apprechiated.

Comment: i suppose you should have events in your soundInstance (something like Started/Stopped/Paused/Finished/etc). then you can subscribe to Finished event in your SoundManager and remove finished instance from sAllSounds

Comment: Thanks, that sounds useful. I'll have to further look into events.

Comment: Please look at: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/137973/with-monogame-is-it-possible-to-await-soundeffect-or-soundeffectinstance-before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I avoided this problem by making my own sound class: It gets initialized with a SoundEffect, stores the duration property, creates a SoundEffectInstance and drops the SoundEffect. The SoundManager class holds a list of these new SoundEffect class. Each Instance gets updated every Frame, and sets a flag it the duration has been reached. The SoundManager delets the Instance from the list within the next frame.